# How to properly return value in async function when there are lot of callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await

I have an async function, that calls other async functions, and when they are all done, I'm returning the results.

I don't wanna use `Promise.all`, because in case any of these functions fail, I just don't add them to my results.

ATM my code looks like this. It works, but I don't like the `new Promise`, I wanna do it in ES6 async way, so the callAll function should look like `const callAll = async (query) => {`

```
const callAll = (query) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const results = [];

        const jobs = [
            {
                promise: someModuleFirst.search(query), 
                done: false
            },
            {
                promise: someModuleSecond.search(query),
                done: false
            },
            {
                promise: someModuleThird.search(query),
                done: false    
            }
        ];

        const areAllDone = () => {
            if(!jobs.filter((job) => !job.done).length) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        jobs.forEach((job) => {
            job.promise.then((result) => {
                job.done = true;

                results.push(result);

                if(areAllDone()) {
                    resolve(results);
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                job.done = true; 

                if(areAllDone()) {
                    resolve(results);
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Have you checked out the `async` module? It will save you a lot of head scratching

Comment: @borislemke the `async.parallel` doesn't seem to accept Promises on first argument, I don't wanna do any weird hacks and transform promises to callbacks, I'm trying to make the code as nice as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably reduce your code to the following. You can return false from the `catch` handler, then filter out the data, which won't get passed into the result set.

```
const callAll = async (query) => {
    const modules = [someModuleFirst, someModuleSecond, someModuleThird];
    const jobs = modules.map((module) => module.search(query).catch(() => false);
    const results = await Promise.all(jobs);
    return results.filter(Boolean);
};
```

Comment: actually, It'll pass `undefined` to the result set, it's okay though, just would be nice to note it in the answer

Comment: Starting to get a bit messy now haha, but you can return false and just `filter` those out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Promise.all` the only thing you need to do is to cache rejection and turn it into resolve.

```js
function someAsyncFunction() {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function () {
   if (Math.round(Math.random() * 100) % 2) {
    return resolve('some result');
   }
   reject('some rejection');
  })
 }, 1);
}
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // this is important part
  // catch block returns a promise with is resolved
  // so all promises now will resolve
 promises.push(someAsyncFunction().catch(function (reason) {
  return reason;
 }));
}
Promise.all(promises).then(function (results) {
  console.log('All resolved');
 console.log(results);
}).catch(function (reason) {
 console.error('Rejected');
 console.log(reason);
});
```

So in your case you need to change `someModuleFirst.search(query)` into some thing like this `someModuleFirst.search(query).catch(e => e)`

Comment: Thanks! That's a great idea, I'm not gonna accept it yet though, maybe someone has a better approach